# Why does VASP use -O2 optimization by default rather than -O3?

Tags: vasp, programming

When compiling VASP, I am wondering why the

```
 OFLAG = -O2
```

is suggested as default. For performance reason, I would use

```
 OFLAG = -O3
```

Could someone help explain the reason?

EDIT: I asked this question because I used the DFT code FHI-aims, whose compilation is suggested with optimization level:

```
FFLAGS = -O3 -ip -fp-model precise
```

In addition, I use intel compiler.

Answer (score 12):

This is a great question! Only a VASP developer involved in making that decision would be able to tell you precisely why they made that decision, but I will give you as many useful pieces of information related to this topic as I can. Many of these are from a 10-year old thread in StackOverflow that currently has 144,000+ views: "[Is optimisation level -O3 dangerous in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546263/1271772)"

- Applying `-O3` to an **entire program** that is as large as VASP, can cause it to run slower because it would generate more machine code than `-O2` which would then make the program unable to fit in the L1 cache. For "large" programs this can also be true for `-O2` vs `-O1` or `-O0`. VASP is a "large" program, but I don't know if it's large enough for `-O2` to cause this type of slow-down (hopefully the developers who decided to set `-O2` to be the default, considered this carefully enough). **The [intended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985801/1271772) use of `-O3` is that you manually apply it to a *small* number of files *if* they contain  critical inner loops that actually benefit from these aggressive space-for-speed tradeoffs.**
- `-O3` has also been known to have many [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546263/1271772) in the past, but the most upvoted answer in the linked StackOverflow thread says that this was "over a decade ago" (and since that answer was written in July 2012, it would now be over "two decades ago" that this was a problem). It's possible that the tendency for `-O3` to have bugs was a factor 20+ years ago in making the decision to make `-O2` the default. However, while the top-voted answer in that thread says that the bugs were only a problem 20+ years before 2022, an [answer in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154063/1271772) from a compiler developer, says that it was still a problem recently.
- `-O3` generally will make compilation take longer (often by a very significant amount), and will make the size of the overall program's executables take up much more space. For a big program like VASP, space can be a concern, and even the time to compile can be a concern (a much smaller program called [mrcc](/questions/tagged/mrcc) has sometimes taken me more than 24 hours to compile, which can be enough for your compilation to be interrupted/cut-off due to it being a "job" that takes too long on a shared supercomputer). The longer compile time and larger space required for `-O3` in VASP is probably insignificant when compared to the amount of time that VASP is being run (i.e. the use that you're getting out of the compilation), but certainly for smaller programs like my [FeynDyn software](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465513002294) for numerical Feynman integrals for quantum dynamics, I chose a lot of default settings with the overall user experience in mind rather than only the speed and accuracy of the calculations. I would rather them be able to get started very quickly and without trouble (i.e. bugs in using `-O3` and time/space increases causes by `-O3` would not be preferred) than to have slightly faster calculations in a program ***that is already super fast for most calculations no matter what level of optimization is used.*** This bullet point applies to most scientific software in general rather than just to VASP.
- Optimization often requires care and attention rather than just blindly using the command with the largest number in it. In [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28895896) where someone was complaining about a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) program being slower with `-O3` when compared to `-O2`, someone posted the following code timings:

```
-O2 -g: 1.07s
-O3 -g: 1.17s
-O3 -g -fprofile-generate/use: 0.84s
```

Comment: GCC12 makes `-ftree-vectorize` part of `-O2`, like is already the case for `clang`.  If GCC `-O3` is going to take more space, that's usually the reason, since `-O3` hasn't included `-funroll-loops` for a long time.  Back when `-O3` enabled loop unrolling all over the place, code bloat was more of a problem with using `-O3`, that's why it was changed to only be enabled by `-fprofile-use` (so GCC knows which loops are hot and worth spending code size on).

Comment: (Also, in the Pentium 4 days, I-cache footprint was even more importnat because the legacy decoders were slow and the trace cache was small.  It's still much better for current CPUs for code fetch to hit in the L1i or preferably the uop cache, but even L2 hits aren't a disaster if branch prediction is working well, so code fetch is pretty far ahead of execution, keeping the out-of-order window full of work to pick from.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with VASP specifically, but **most numerical / scientific computing code spends most of its time in a few loops (small code footprint)**, so optimizing the crap out of them is worth it.  Especially auto-vectorization can be a big win, if it's not already enabled at `-O2` with `#pragma omp simd ...` and `-fopenmp` to enable that.  Even if you get some I-cache misses, that can be worth it if it's once at the start of a new phase of the program, starting a new loop.

Comment: Of course, for unrolling to be useful, it has to be mitigating a front-end bottleneck, or letting the compiler hide dependency chain bottlenecks, especially in floating point code.  clang tends to be better at this than GCC; GCC will often unroll but still stupidly sum an array into a single XMM/YMM register, defeating the purpose.    (See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) / and [an asm teaching example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095394/224132)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think these comments provide some really good insight and it would be useful to future users to have them put into an answer.

Comment: Another possible reason is that many (sometimes most) operations of a scientific calculation program are spent in BLAS, LAPACK and FFT routines, for which one usually calls precompiled, highly optimized libraries regardless of to what extent the main program is optimized. VASP certainly belongs to this category. On the other hand, in molecular codes, such as BDF that I've been working on, the rate-determining step (calculation of two-electron integrals over Gaussian functions) is mostly in explicit loops, so I've seen ~2x speedups when going from -O2 to -Ofast, at least on some platforms.

Comment: +1 An interesting information I have seen in compilation instructions of many programs is that they recommend -O2 for gcc/gfortran, but -O3 for intel c++ or fortran, because apparently intel's -O3 is more stable.

Comment: @wzkchem5 yes. But I predict many of the scientific programs that previously spent most time in LAPACK etc. calls, will increasingly have bottlenecks in the bespoke parts: because those can't easily be ported to run on GPUs, whereas linear algebra often gets speedups by orders of magnitude, so that even if the vast majority of FLOPS is spent there it can end up being only a small slice of the run time.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes this is true. But on the other hand, many computational tasks can be replaced by numerical integrations, which are BLAS-friendly and parallelize well on GPUs. In BDF we have an option of evaluating the Coulomb and exchange terms with seminumerical integration (the MPEC+COSX approximation), which is the recommended way of doing BDF calculations on GPUs, and even on CPUs this is faster than the analytical calculation by 2x-10x.

Comment: Update re: GCC12 enabling vectorization at `-O2` - only with a much lower cost threshold, so it doesn't actually auto-vectorize most loops with runtime-variable lengths.  See [Is \`-ftree-loop-vectorize\` not enabled by \`-O2\` in GCC v12?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74898622) .  Often you'll want `-O3`.